# Linux compile error for dispatch_get_specific in Swift

Tags: linux, swift

I'm trying to use dispatch_get_specific through a libdispatch module with Swift. When I compile it in Linux I get the error `unresolved identifier 'dispatch_get_specific'`. The other libdispatch functions seem to work. How do I fix this compile error?

Here is a sample project to show the build error [sample project](http://www.filedropper.com/gcd4-master)

Comment: Do you have a minimal example that demonstrates this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It was an old version of libdispatch on Linux